# Should I use a 32 or 64-bit system?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 12.10, system, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

My computer is a Lenovo (2010 model) with 1 GB of RAM, 32 GB of HardDrive (dedicated to Ubuntu), a Intel Core 2 Duo processor. I would like to know which is the right system for my computer (32 or 64 Bits) for optimum performance.

Comment: 32bit. 1GB of RAM is not enough for a 64bit system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, You should take advantage of 64 bit CPU. Install 64 bit version of ubuntu 12.10. Major Difference of  both versions is that you can access maximum only 64 GB RAM in 32 bit and 256 GB in 64 Bit System.

Comment: No, not true the PAE kernel can access well over 4GB of RAM in a 32bit OS, the limit is at ~64GB.

Comment: ...but the OP doesn't have 4GB or 256GB. There is only 1, so what does it matter how much RAM can be accessed in theory?

Comment: 64 Bit gives you better performance than 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your CPU, if your CPU supports 64bit you should probably install the 64bit System.
Since your CPU is Core 2 it supports 64bit, therefore I suggest you to install Ubuntu 12.10 64bit.

Comment: Does the RAM usage will go up with a 64-bits System?

Comment: no it will not, 64bit is just able to handle more ram, it will not increase the usage of it!