# I have an ASUS G74sx.. Want to dual boot ubuntu with windows 7. 32 bit or 64 bit ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

I'm not sure as to what architecture of ubuntu go for... either 32 bit or 64 bit. I'm not sure if to go with the 64 bit since I have 12gb of RAM, so that with 64bit it will cover the 12gb.

Also I would like to know what are the disadvantages of each of them, either 32 or 64. 
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer x86_64. No workarounds to support +4gb of RAM. With 64-bit it is possible to give more than 2GB of RAM to a single process(might be useful in virtualization). And now most of software support 64-bit architecture, unlike it was a couple of years ago.
And the performance is better. If you use native 64-bit software, it is sometimes significantly better.
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_1210_3264

Comment: Thanks for the key detail! Now.. Once I finish downloading the ubuntu 12.10. I made a 55gb partition which is NTFS formatted. How do I install linux on that partition? Or should I do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Advantages and disadvantages of 32-bit:

- All software supported
- Better for gaming because game only use not more than 1GB memory
- Only cover 3.2 GB (***But on PAE cover 64 GB***)

Advantages and disadvantages of 64-bit:

- Use 64-bit software, it is difficult to search 64-bit software.
- Cover more than 4GB memory
- Better for virtualization (if you need)
- Use more memory than the 32-bit

I prefer 32-bit to 64-bit because 32-bit application / software is wide-supported. Then on PAE, Ubuntu can cover all of your memory.

Comment: If you use PAE 32-bit (12.04 and 12.10 I think are PAE only), you can use the full 12GB.

And if you need any 32-bit specific software, such as wine, the multiarch support in Ubuntu should make it mostly easy to install the needed libraries to run them. There are a few exceptions to this rule of course, particularly in the area of plug-ins and loadable runtimes for various applications. However, it is generally not a problem.