# Does 64bit ubuntu takes more memory than 32bit or is "quantal" more demanding than "precise"?

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, memory-usage

I've just clean-installed 12.10 64bit and i noticed an increase in memory usage. I used 12.04 32bit and was running about ~400mb on startup(gnome3 no effects) + firefox, now the machine uses about ~600 mb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

64-bit OS and applications do require more RAM than 32-bit, see this answer for details: https://askubuntu.com/a/70551/14564

While it is possible that the newer Ubuntu also requires more (or less) RAM than the older one, the difference between 400Mb and 600Mb fits well within the difference between 32 and 64 bit OS memory consumption.