# Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit or 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have used Ubuntu for over 2 years now, with 64 bit version always. I have been using 12.04 64 bit ever since it was released. I usually use Ubuntu for development and programming and little bit of browsing but all my other stuff happens in Windows 7. I have noticed that Ubuntu cannot use my DMA and slows down my entire computer when ever I copy or move something as the processor usage spikes up. As my Ubuntu distro has become quite slow, I am planning to re install it. Will installing 32 bit version make any difference to the DMA problem or the other hardware problems? (excessive processor usage etc). I don't play games much, so I don't need entire 6GB of my RAM to be available always. Also, can I give linux mint a try? (I like Unity)
btw, processor is i3
Thanks!

Comment: why not give live cd a try to see if everything is working fine. :)

Comment: Re: *Also, can I give linux mint a try?*: According to the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq), Ask Ubuntu provides support for [recognized Ubuntu flavors](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/derivatives). This aspect of your question may be welcome at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not much difference. I had more Software issues with 64-bit, so I switched to 32-bit. My feeling was it is a little slower. With PAE you will have your 6GB RAM and you have it with the I3.

So, if you don't have software issues - use 64-bit, but maybe 12.10...