# Should I use 32bit version of ubuntu 12.10 or 64bit version?

Tags: 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

After using Ubuntu 12.10 for awhile on a separate computer, I decided to dual boot on my windows machine.
The only bad thing is that I do not know which version of Ubuntu 12.10 to use 32bit or 64bit. I have been using 12.10 on another computer but it was as 32bit version and people have been saying that some hardware might not be supported in 64bit.

My build is:
-i5 3570k
-nvidia 560ti 
-8gb ram
-Asus mobo
-Two drives (320gb and 1tb)

Any help on which version to use is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

With your CPU architecture and your 8GB ram go for the 64bit version.

Comment: Would going with the 64bit version deny me some uses that are in 32bit?

Comment: Well, chances are that some software wont run on 64bit platform (although things are improving). 
For instance:I wanted to run GuitarPro. Its propriatery software which is only released in a 32 bit version. 

If you know of any specific software you want to run (especially Prop. Software) I would check if it will run on 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks for the help and quick reply but I'm just going to go with 32bit since some of my software does not run in 64bit.

Comment: 32-bit libraries and programs generally work fine on the 64-bit version of Ubuntu. Maybe you could boot the PC from a live USB and see if your software runs?

Comment: I'll go try that but for another question, What is the pro of going with 64bit instead of 32bit?

Comment: generally speaking 64 bit is faster

Comment: I guess I'll use 64bit and hope that in future reference if I try to install something it works with 64bit. Thanks guys for all the help.