# Updated answers for 32 bit vs 64 bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have Intel 3rd gen processor i5 & ATI Radeon 7670m GPU in my 64 bit Laptop.
I want to install Ubuntu.
But I am not able ti understand which version to Install.
The answers for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose) question are old.
So I wanted to know the answers for the latest Ubuntu i.e. 12.10.
Thank You.