# Which Ubuntu can I install in my computer?

Tags: system-requirements

I have one motherboard (Asrock,model P4I65GV)and I don't know which Ubuntu its the correct software to put it!Is better the x32bit bit or x64 bit?please can someone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar), and [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your CPU, not the motherboard. If your CPU supports 64-bit you should use the 64-bit.