# Should I download the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version of Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, downloads, 32-bit, macbook

I have a 13" Macbook Pro 2010. Should I download the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do and your system but this question may help [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/q/7034/107450)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google, your MacBook has 4GB of RAM memory. The rule of thumb to use is that you should install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu if you have more than 3GB of RAM and if your CPU supports a 64-bit OS. [Intel Core 2 Duo CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_2_Duo#Core_2_Duo) support 64-bit OSs, so you should choose the 64-bit version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 32bit uses PAE, so the limit of total RAM is 64 GB (with most CPUs). I'd recommend 64bit because of the expected performance gain through command set extensions that are common for all 64bit CPUs, but might not be availabe on some 32bit models (and therefore cannot be used system wide on a 32bit OS). A drawback of the 64bit version is that programs usually use more RAM than with 32bit, due to the twice as large pointer data type. Also keep in mind that Ubuntu is a multilib OS, so the 64bit version can run nearly all 32bit programs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The way you work this out is by looking up what sort of CPU you have and then looking up that CPU to see what it supports. In your case:

1. [The 2010 MBP uses a Intel Core 2 Duo P8600](http://apcmag.com/apple-macbook-pro-2010-vs-2011-models-compared-spec-by-spec.htm)
2. [The P8600 has a 64-bit instruction set](http://ark.intel.com/products/35568/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-P8600-3M-Cache-2_40-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB)

64-bit should be fine. 32bit will also work.