# Can I totaly install Ubuntu 64bit on my computer?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, cpu-architecture

I run the `lscpu` command on Ubuntu and this is the result:

```
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 23
Stepping:              10
CPU MHz:               1600.000
BogoMIPS:              5599.80
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              3072K
```

I have bought my computer about 5 years ago. All these years I thought it can just support 32-bits. Now I found out `CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit` means that my CPU also supports 64-bits.

I want to know if I can totally install a 64-bit OS on my computer? Is there any other thing to know? Does my computer totally meet all requirements to have 64-bit OS installed?

Comment: Why do you need to install 64-bit? How much RAM does your computer have? 32-bit can use all 4GB RAM if you have <= 4GB RAM.

Comment: How much RAM? If less than 2GB then not much advantage. A few motherboards have 64bit cpu, but not 64 bit support chips. If you can boot 64 bit live installer in live mode then it will work. My laptop from 2006 runs 64 bit, but with only 1.5GB of RAM, I cannot load more than one large app and a couple of smaller apps before it starts using swap and gets real slow.

Comment: @Karel 32-bit can use 64gb of ram with the linux PAE extension...

Comment: I use 64-bit on my asus eee pc laptop from 2010, but it had 2GB when I started and that felt a bit slow, now with 4GB it's just fine.

Comment: @Alvar Already knew that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/318418/should-i-download-the-32-bit-version-or-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu/318421#comment403694_318421 I'd be surprised if a computer with that CPU has more than 4GB RAM.

Comment: @karel I'm not going to install more RAM. I just want to be able to run 64-bit apps.

Comment: What do you have to lose by trying it?

Comment: @ElderGeek I wasn't aware about Live installer. I will give it a try.