# Working very slow after some time

Tags: 12.04

I have just started working on Ububtu 12.04.When I turned on, after some time it gets hanged for 2 sec and after the processing speed gets slows down.
Any suggestions?

Comment: could you please add some more details? especially details regarding the hardware that you're running Ubuntu on.

Answer (score 2):

A *possible* cause is that you are running out of available RAM. When that happens, contents of the computers RAM are "swapped" to the HDD, which is orders of magnitude slower than RAM, leading to generally very bad performance.

There are many possible reasons for filled up memory. The two most probable ones:

- The most probable one is that the Ubuntu desktop is too heavy for your computer.

  - If you have less than 4 GB of RAM, Ubuntu 12.04 **64bit** is hardly usable (Been there, done that...). Since 32bit is supposed to [use less memory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose), you could instead use the 32bit edition of Ubuntu.
  - You can try to use RAM saving apps instead of memory eaters. Use Claws-Mail instead of Evolution for E-Mail, xpdf or ePDFviewer instead of evince, Gnome Browser (aka epiphany-browser) instead of Firefox, mousepad, leafpad or even emacs or vim instead of gedit,...
  - Another option is to use a more lightweight desktop. Xfce and Lxde are good candidates, because they work well without desktop effects (which use easily more than 200 MB RAM). If you are also looking for a selection of RAM saving apps, you can install the lubuntu-desktop or xubuntu-desktop packages or start with Xubuntu/Lubuntu directly. (There are also other Distributions designed to be even more lightweight.)
  - This problem can also be simply "solved" by adding more RAM to your PC ;-)
- Another possible cause is a bug in a running program, a so called "memory leak".

  - You can check the memory usage for instance by running `top` in terminal. To sort for real (residual) RAM usage, press upper case O and then select the RES field (probably by pressing q). There are of course many other options to [check memory usage](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-memory-usage/). If there is a single program using lots and lots of RES, you can be almost certain that something is not OK with that software. In such a case, please write a bug report and if possible, avoid using that program until a fix is released.
  - If on the other hand a driver is having a memory leak, it will not be shown in `top`. If you are lucky, you can use `slabtop` to identify which kernel data structure is using RAM (maybe slabtop has to be run with sudo). Especially the proprietary nVidia driver has has an extremely bad memory leak in Ubuntu 9.? causing it to make a computer unusable within hours, no matter how much RAM a system had. If it's the graphics driver, you can switch between proprietary and open source. For drivers that come with the kernel, [changing the kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) is probably the only option.