# Installing 12.10

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded ubuntu 12.10 on a usb stick and followed all instructions as given. But when I try to install it on hardrive or run it. It says that I have the wrong linux kernel for this cpu. It's a intel celeron m. What am I doing wrong plz help

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose

Answer (score 1):

You may have downloaded a 64bit version and your Laptop may have a 32bit processor. And hence the error. Download a 32bit ISO and then check, the error wont pop up. For 32bit do not download the `x86_x64` version, that is 64bit Download the i386 / i686 version.