# replace 32bit with 64bit advantage

Tags: uninstall

My first post.  Successfully migrated from win 7 to ubuntu 12.04.1 on my samsung netbook. working smoothly.  But I had installed 32 bit version.  Is there any advantage of going in for 64 bit?  What are the risks.
Ram Prasad

Comment: Depending on your netbook (which?) you may have a 32-bit CPU only. You won't be able to run and install 64-bit Ubuntu then.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Try reading this answer [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose) and this website http://www.howtogeek.com/165144/htg-explains-should-you-use-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-edition-of-ubuntu-linux/

They should answer your question, if not, try googling `difference between ubuntu 32 bit and 64 bit`. That brought up several good sites.