# can I get ubuntu 13.04 64 bit when I have 3gb of ram

Tags: 64-bit

I have an Intel dual-core CPU 2.0 ghz and 3GB of RAM. My motherboard is a DQ965GF.

I looked at the user manual and saw it supports 64 bit OS's and so does my CPU. I want to know if I can do this and have a decent 64 bit OS.

Comment: Yes, I use full Ubuntu with 1.5GB on old laptop but with gnome-fallback not Unity. But video can be an issue also. What video card/chip do you have. And if not newer then Xubutu, Lubuntu or gnome-fallback may be better choices. You can just test with liveDVD or flash drive installer.

Comment: Are you referring to my GPU? If so it is an AMD R710 Gallium 0.4 and I am using Unity, it actually works fine right form the live USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your processor supports 64-bit operations, then you should install the 64-bit Ubuntu. The amount of RAM is acceptable, so it will not be a problem.

See [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, 64-bit works great. I am happy with the switch from 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should run fine with 3 gig of RAM. The real question is what do your APPS require.

But web browsing etc should run just fine.

Comment: netflix seems to be the only issue with 64-bit

Comment: I've had problems with any flash site (HBOGo, Google Play) with x64

Answer (score 0):

64-bits only refers to the architecture of the processor. The memory limitations that it prevents is a *plus*. Is being said that if your processor supports 64-bits, then the recommended installation should be 64-bits.

But remember, that 64-bits builds tend to be more resources intensive than 32-bits counter parts. Also, some software is not available in 64-bits, and that could cause set backs.

Bottom line, if your system supports 64-bits and you think that there is no problem using 64-bits, go for it. The benefits of using 64-bits are practically null and is well known that 32bit OS's can be installed in 64-bits processors without problem.

Comment: "The benefits of using 64-bits are practically null" This statement is untrue. Most hardware sold today takes advantage things that need 64 bit OSes to fully utilize. There is a reason the entire industry is taking the time to move off 32 bit platforms.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins why you bring only 1 statement into discussion without caring about the question itself? My statement in the context of the question is correct. No benefits will come to OP using one or another. It may actually be counterproductive using 64-bits in a system with less of 4GB of memory (and then there is PAE). If you like to show me the advantage of 64-bits in the context of OP's question, be my guess.

Comment: Well, if he adds a gig of RAM it will make a difference. Also see my actual answer below, that is why I made it as a comment.