# How to select the architecture to download?

Tags: release-management

I'm a completely new user of Linux and since my computer is not a good machine I wanted to install 32 bit OS, I downloaded ubuntu desktop for 32 bit but when I check in system settings under details it says my OS type is 64 bit, I downloaded it from the site http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop choose Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and set it as 32-bit (machines with less than 2GB RAM).

Comment: what do you see when you open a terminal and type: uname -a

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1~Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 16:19:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure I downloaded the 32-bit one, the problem is I have only about 1.7GB ram. I reinstalled and downloaded the 32 bit version again but no difference, still says its 64 bit

Comment: @Braiam I added the link of my download, it sure was the one for 32 bit. I just started to download both of the versions and the names of ISO files are different

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu download page defaults to 64-bit images. Most likely you just pressed download or pressed the wrong button:

[image]

If you change one menu, and click the other button, it will defaults to 64-bits.

If you don't trust that, you can verify the file sizes:

### 32 bits

[image]

### 64 bits

[image]

You can also use hotlink:

- 64 bits LTS: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=lts&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc
- 32 bits LTS: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=lts&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc

Or go directly to http://releases.ubuntu.com and download your image.

Comment: thank you very much for the information on this, I guess its surely a 32 bit version since in my downloads is a i386.iso.

Comment: If you feel that my answer answered your question, mark it as accepted.