# how can I install Ubuntu on my old computer

Tags: system-installation

I've been trying to download and install Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 6000 laptop computer with no luck.
It's an old computer about 9 years old.
It has intel 1.6g processor and 2 gigs of memory.
I had tried to install one of the Ubuntu but I got a message that says I need an x86-64.

I have a 32bit laptop.

I have only one hard drive with windows XP on it,

How can I purchase a Ubuntu O.S. or download the correct Ubuntu for my particular computer but a current system where I can get support.

Comment: *"...but I got a message that says I need an x86-64."* This means you tried to install the 64-bit version. [Since your computer has a 32-bit processor, you need to use the 32-bit Ubuntu instead.](http://askubuntu.com/q/7034) So on [the download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) select 32-bit under "Choose your flavour." (It says the 32-bit version is for computers with < 2 GB RAM, but it's also for computers with 32-bit CPUs and any amount of RAM.) [Installation is as usual.](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328) (Or you may want [something lighter](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407).)

Comment: Probably you read backwards, and what it said is "that you need a x86-64" CPU. Try with the 32-bit CD instead.

Answer (score 3):

firstly Ubutnu is free; you don't purchase it but you can donate if you want to. :)

...according to your information you have a "32bit" system so you should download the 32bit version of ubuntu. here's the download link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=latest (scroll down; there's a hyperlink to the left)

try again and feed me back here ; )

...I have something more to tell you; there are two supported Ubuntu versions: 12.04 LTS and 13.10. The link above is for 13.10; I recommend it for you.

13.10 is the most up to date version but will be supported for a short time (about 5 months left); this is just because newer versions will come up so they stop supporting 13.10 to support the new one (which will be 14.04). 12.04 is not the newest version but will be supported long (several years).

put in mind that it's so easy to upgrade Ubuntu 13.10 to the next version later from the update manager; just a few clicks and you're there! Anyways it's up to you :), here's the link to 12.04 http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/questions?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts

---

edit: those suggestions below are great! (the LXDE and the LXLE!)

I've never heard about LXLE but I *do* use LXDE!! YOU CAN INSTALL LXDE AFTER YOU INSTALL THE REGULAR UBUNTU!! Actually LXDE is ubuntu but with lighter user interface and apps. After installing ubuntu you can install the LXDE interface from the "ubuntu software center" and then you can chose which interface you want on each startup! the regular "unity" interface or the LXDE! That way you have both!! : )

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to try Lubuntu. With 2 GB of RAM, Ubuntu will swap, hence slow down the system once a while. And if your processor is a P4, it would be slow; Unity is quite heavy.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu

Another interesting alternative is Linux Mint. The XFCE version is lightweight and yet has a very good looking.

http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=113

Comment: Note that `lubuntu` is a real ubuntu, and `mint` is a (popular, good) fork. This means that here, lubuntu is on topic, but mint is not.

Comment: @djeikyb Agreed. It's perfectly appropriate to inform people of other distros in answers, though. **cochisebt**: What about the Xfce version of Ubuntu, [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)? It's not as lightweight as [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), but it takes up fewer resources than a "vanilla" [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) (or [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) system). Is there any special reason to prefer the Xfce version of Mint over Xubuntu? Is it more lightweight?

Comment: To my point of view, XFCE version of Mint has a nicer look than Xubuntu, and would be more intuitive to use for someone who is used with Windows. Howevr, Xubuntu is also a very good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind the laptop in question is quite old and probably has a Pentium M chip. Some of these CPU's lack the PAE flag which prevents a simple install.  If that is the case then LXLE is a good option.

Comment: There is a workaround – before Linux kernel is loaded (purple screen) you have to press ESC, select Install Ubuntu, press F6, ESC and after `[...] quiet splash --` type `forcepae` then press Enter.