# AMD64 or i386 for Acer Aspire 5530G

Tags: 32-bit, amd-processor

I have laptop Acer aspire 5530G: AMD Turion X2 Ultra Dual-Core Mobile ZM-80 2.1 with 2GB RAM.
So, What is Ubuntu better: amd64 or i386? if CPU amd, but RAM is 2 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU can run both versions. Which version you install is more or less up to you, however, its recommended to have 4 GB RAM to run amd64 version, which you lack so its up to you, but please check the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose) to learn the difference between 32 and 64 bits.