# Mouse pointer is not visible on a fresh installation of 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, mouse

Yesterday I installed 14.04 on my dell latitude e6430. After the instalation when system started mouse pointer is not visible and the touchpad and mouse are, hence, useless.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I get hundreds of links that point to similar problems though they are not on 14.04. Did you try any of those?

Comment: I've start to dig in into this case, since now i don't find any good solution. I just test gsettings set org.gnome.settings-deamon.plugins.cursor active false/true but there is no such settings

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem on my Thinkpad x120e after a fresh install of ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64 (64 bit Ubuntu). I would log into Ubuntu and the mouse would disappear, right click wouldn't do anything, and all of the other remedies that I saw posted didn't have any effect.

What worked for me:

I did a clean install Ubuntu 14.04 **32-bit** edition instead of the recommended 64-bit version. It works great now!

Another user mentioned that a bit more background on this may be helpful. Here goes, a post under the question: 'what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose' talks about some key differences 32 bit and 64 bit and an obvious one is compatibility... 32 bit is generally more compatible with everything.

> The practical problem: not everyone has a AMD64 compatible CPU.
>   Promoting 64-bit over the standard i686 version would lead to more
>   user frustration. Therefore for the next few years, it's less
>   confusing to present the 32-bit version to the average user. It's not
>   exactly a problem for anyone in the know, since the 64-bit version is
>   readily available. And we amd64 users don't have any disadvantage from
>   that situation, except for the initial download. All packages are
>   available in both architectures.

https://askubuntu.com/a/7084/284653

Not saying for sure that the mouse pointer disappearing was due to an architecture issue but it does seem to fit for this instance. Hope this works for you.

Comment: I would 'fill out' your answer, if at all possible.  Search for other questions that might be similar and see if there is advice that you can include along with your 32-bit solution.  For instance, I might recommend [differences between 32-bit and 64-bit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)