# Changing Ubuntu version

Tags: upgrade, cpu

So, my friend lent me his Ubuntu 12.10 boot CD, and it's the 64-bit version, but my processor is 32-bit. So, after installing, I was wondering if there's a way to install 14.04 32-bit from inside the system itself. Thanks!

Comment: There is no need for calling names @begueradj

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/157001/65926

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), select 32-bit, hit download. Mount to USB or burn to DVD and install.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04) *should* work with 12.10 as well as 12.04

Make sure to make backups of anything important before trying this though, just in case.