# Try to install 64 bit version of Lubuntu

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, 64-bit, system-installation

I have an old PC with AMD Sempron 3000+ and a half GB of ram.
I also have an old laptop with Intel Core 2 Duo and 1GB of ram.
If I am not wrong they are 64 bits version of processors.

I try to run live CD of Lubuntu 14.04 amd64 version and both: success.
but when install it, both: failed. I used USB flash disk to run live cd.

Is there any explanations of these?
Btw, I usually use 32 bits version.
Thanks..

Comment: Are you sure you have a 64-bit processor?

Comment: What do you mean by "success" and "failed"? What works and what doesn't?

Comment: I am not sure. I currently browse the web about their specifications. they show 64 bits. I try some commands the output double: 32 bits, 64 bits. Just like they can handle both..? I just want to know..

Comment: success: running well no error shown. failed: can install but cannot boot into login window.

Comment: Sorry I just need the Year the intel Laptop was made so I can determine if its 64 bit or not

Comment: i bought them around 2007 - 2008, maybe, sorry i am forget about the year.. :)

Comment: Please read this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/70551/265974. "So, if your system has, say, 2GiB of RAM or less then I would definitely choose 32 bits"

Comment: @Xubu-Tur : ok, I use 32-bit version. because it just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Intel does show what processors have what technical Specs on Processor chips.
[This is what you should look at.](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/79667/Legacy-Intel-Core2-Processor#@All)

I did not see an Intel Chip that wasn't 64 bit.  However your [Sempron is a 32 bit and will not accept a 64 bit install.](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K7/AMD-Sempron%203000+%20-%20SDA3000DUT4D%20%28SDA3000BOX%29.html)

As a rule of thumb, anything under 4 GB of RAM should have a 32 bit OS installed.

Comment: The last answer is incorrect for Linux? The 32 bit version of Ubuntu needs only 512MB RAM and the 64 bit only 1024MB RAM, it will be slow but must work.

Comment: @Korkel How did you get these values? Ubuntu Unity should need at least 1GB RAM -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: @Virusboy : I read link you gave.. and it shows that Sempron has 32-bit and 64-bit operating mode..? am i wrong..?

Comment: I updated the link to improve the answer

Comment: I bought 1GB DDR2 for my PC. Now, I have 1.5GB ram. I don't know how, now it work the Lubuntu 14.04 amd64 version. btw, I try run lscpu in command line it shows: 32 bits, 64 bits.

Comment: Sempron 3000+ is 64bit. I have installed Ubuntu Server 14.04LTS (64bit only) with Lubuntu desktop on a system with above cpu and almost 1GB RAM. It won't win any races, but it works.

Comment: @Wastono TunKsn has provided a proper wiki link that describes having 2 GB for day to day use to be best.  I use four as a line of what would worked best between switching from 32 bit use to 64 bit use