# Whenever I install Ubuntu it says please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU

Tags: kernel, cpu

Whenever I try to install Ubuntu it says the kernel is not appropriate for my CPU. Or tell me an OS that's Minecraft capable and for an i686 processor.

Comment: My guess is you are using 64 bit ubuntu on a 32 bit CPU. Use the 32 bit version. http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose

Comment: What CPU do you have? And what is the full error?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar messages when attempting to install Ubuntu on hardware with a processor that doesn't support [physical address extensions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE).  This can also happen when attempting to install a 64-bit image on 32-bit hardware.

If the issue is PAE-related, you can attempt the steps outlined in the linked documentation.

- The first step is to attempt adding the kernel flag `forcepae` to the kernel boot options
- If this doesn't help, since modern Ubuntu releases no longer support non-PAE hardware, you can try some options the documentation recommends, such as Xubuntu 12.04, nOS, Bodhi Linux, Lubuntu 12.04, or Puppy Retro.  The linked documentation also provides some more difficult steps you could potentially take to get Ubuntu 12.04 installed.