# which release do i use

Tags: unetbootin

I am trying to install Ubuntu for the first time and have been unsuccessful. I am using Unetbootin. First i used the 14.04_Live distribution and was told i had a corrupt kernel. I then used 14.04_HDMedia. it trys to boot up, scrolls rapidly through several pages of notifications about what it is doing and such. It then hangs on a dark blank screen.

I welcome advice, but my first thought is, maybe I'm using the wrong distribution for my laptop.

Which distribution should I use for the following PC

HP Pavillion DV-5000
32 bit 
XP
windows media center.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your Turion 64 (mobile) CPU is 64 bit so you can install both 32 or 64 bit Ubuntu. However if you don't have special reason to install 32-bit you are recommended to install 64bit OS for performance benefits.

Download [Ubuntu 64 bit](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/contribute/?version=14.04&architecture=amd64)

Another issue could be a corrupting. It is possible at both steps: downloading as well as burning image.

Compare `md5sum` of downloaded .iso with the original one and the write image. After it is written check its `md5sum` with the original one again.

Ubuntu hashes you can find [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

Comment: 64-bit Ubuntu is NOT recommended for the HP Pavilion dv5000 which has only 1GB of RAM. For more information about this topic see [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose).

Comment: @karel Maybe it is 2GB of RAM, who knows, is not precised in the question. Many people run 64bit OS on 1Gb and don't know problems. It it's 1Gb I would recommend update to 2Gb. They cost like peanuts nowadays.