# 32 bit or 64bit ubuntu based distro for my machine

Tags: nvidia, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am relative new user and i like ubuntu based distros (since i can google everythng up and make it work without overheating my brain) and i was wandering what ubuntu based distro would you recommend for me (since my plan is to switch completely to linux and use it as main OS on my PC) my PC configuration is  >>> AMD Athlon 64 x2 Dual Core 4200+  2.19GHz >> 2GB RAM >>> Nvidia GeForce 8400 GS.I did tryed a lot of dystros and first question alwayse is should i download 32bit or 64 bit since i have 64 bit CPU but only 2 GB ram  O.o  Ubuntu somehow since 10.01 LTS (was the latest perfectly working version) wasnt working good on my machine and i dont know why...So 32but or 64bit ubuntu based distro and what distro for my PC. Thank you.

Comment: Try this question: [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Comment: I think it is not working for me since a lot have changed since 2011 when this discussion have taken place.Now even ubuntu suggest 64bit os download and it doesnt say anything about ram.That is why i asked question to confirm / deny  "if u have less then 4GB ram 32 bit no metter what CPU" answer.

Comment: The question may be from 2011, but it is still relevant, and is being updated (thats why this has been marked as a duplicate - all updates etc go to that question, so there is one reliable source of info on this site, instead of several of varying quality.)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using 32-bit Ubuntu, though your CPU is 64-bit, since your system has only 2GB RAM. Atleast 4GB RAM would justify installing a 64bit OS