# 64-bit Ubuntu vs 32-bit Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

If I have 3GB RAM, can I install a 64-bit Ubuntu? I'm a little confused because when choosing  the 32-bit it says it's for machines with less than 2GB RAM.

Comment: If your CPU is 64-bit you can. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the CPU architecture you have. If your CPU is a 64bit processor the go for 64bit OS. Has nothing to do with you RAM.

Comment: My computer has a 32-bit processor.

Comment: Then 64bit OS won't work. Go for 32bit. What processor do you have?

Comment: It shure sticks together: 32 bit processors cannot use more than 4 GiB of RAM.