# Computer requirements for 64-bit version of Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit

I'm just downloading a 64-bit 14.04.1 LTS version of Ubuntu but I'm not sure if it will work good on my computer, I'd like to know what you think would it be better to install a 32-bit version or 64-bit?

From System info (Hewlett-Packard laptop Pavilion G6):

Processor: Intel Pentium CPU B950 2.1GHz x 2. Memory: 3.9 GiB. Graphics Card: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Comment: You're fine for 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can install 64 bit Ubuntu on it. Just checked the Intel website for you if your processor supports the 64 bit instruction set and it does. :) 32 bit Ubuntu is even scheduled to get phased out in the near future by Canonical.

Best way to test if it truly works on your system is to just make a bootable USB device or CD and boot your system with it to see if everything works as intended.

Comment: So CPU is ok, but RAM? From what I was reading 4 GB of RAM seems to be the minimum. I have 3.9 if this is it?

Comment: You posted that you have 3.9GB of RAM memory. That is more than enough to run Ubuntu smoothly. :) I believe the recommended minimum amount is 512MB, so you're well above that.

Comment: OK. I'm also asking this because the ventilator in my laptop from time to time starts moving fast, I mean you can hear it. For example when I'm watching a fullscreen HD video on youtube. Any ideas why would that be? Something to do with Flash Player? Because of hardware?

Comment: Could I check with some software if everything is ok?

Comment: Hm, well it is normal that the fan will spin faster when doing heavier stuff like watching HD movies. If the laptop gets hot though, you might want to check if there isn't any dust clogging up the fans first.

Comment: Ok. For now I will install the new Ubuntu and then I'll check other issues, I need to find something simmilar to Task Manager in Ubuntu. Thanks for your replies. Regards.

Comment: No problem and good luck. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question! :D

Comment: It did answer what I asked but I can't vote. I need 15 reputation. EDIT: found it;)

Comment: Click the check mark button under the voting arrows ;) Should give you some rep too!