# 64-bit or 32-bit for chromebook w/ 2gb RAM?

Tags: system-installation, ram

To be specific, the computer is the Acer CB3-111-C670. 32-bit is recommended for devices w/ less than 2GB RAM, but i'm not sure if that applies in this case.

Comment: You have 2GB RAM. 32-bit is recommended for less... I don't see the problem. You're meeting the requirements for 64-bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely 32bit. Even the Intel Celeron N2830 CPU has the ability to run 64bit, you will not use it due to your low RAM 2GB.

Comment: 64 bit is about a lot more than handling more than 4 gb of ram; it also executes faster.