# Ubuntu 32bit or 64bit on a laptop with 4gb ram?

Tags: 64-bit, ram, 32-bit, amd-processor

My laptop has 4Gb of ram and the processor can suport 64bit.
What should I install, 32bit or 64bit? And why?
As far as I know the 32bit version will use less ram but at max 4gb of ram.

Comment: This is up to you. It is opinion based. I am typing this from a comp with 4GB of RAM and a 64-bit system.

Comment: ok thank you very much. PS: i do not understand why on this forum people give negative votes to some questions when they even don t read them

Comment: The question is downvoted, because it is a poor question. You can find a lot of good questions and answers regarding 32 vs 64 here and on other sites. This question is not answerable. It is opinion-based and it will be closed soon.

Comment: i searched before but none of them had the explanation i needed. most of them focus on copy-paste what they find about 32bit/64bit on wikipedia and post it as an answer. my question was specific. anyway thank you for your time, have a nice day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 64 bit system can run 32bit applications as well, but if you have 32 bit system you are not able to run 64 bit applications. Some 64bit only examples are Spotify and Viber. I did not even see the 32bit Viber native linux client. If your system is able to run 64 bit, even with 4GB RAM, then take the advantage of the 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've only ever ran 64bit operating systems on my laptops and desktops and have never had a problem. I've also found, like another person has already said, that I have never had an issue with programs that only support 64bit(Obviously) where I probably would have if I had installed the 32bit OS.

Probably worth noting that I am writing this off a mid 2010 HP Envy laptop with only 4gb RAM and 64bit Ubuntu installed already.

Go the 64bit :)