# what version of ubuntu should i install on my laptop

Tags: 14.04

should i install the x32 or the x64 and what is the difference? also is ubuntu 14 better then ubuntu 15? Also what is the difference in all the flavors of ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform you choose (x32,x64) depends on your CPU architecture. Check your CPU. Which version of Ubuntu is better? It depends on your needs. Read carefully this page and you will get it. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS