# Better linux version for Dell Optiplex 780

Tags: dell

I just got this Dell Optiplex 780 and I'm wondering which linux/ubuntu to install on it and where to find it. Mr. google offered no help to me in this case.
+ How do I know if it should be 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose

Answer (score 0):

You can install pretty much any variant of Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution on your machine, and all the hardware is well supported.

You can download Ubuntu from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. There are also many other variants of Ubuntu, such as [Kubuntu](http://kubuntu.org) or [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/), with KDE, and MATE desktop, respectively, as well as many other options. ([Here's a list of the various choices and what they offer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)). Just pick what you like best.

Comment: It might be good to add the strengths, purposes etc. of each DE.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju No; that would made the answer opinion-based, and in any case it is not asked in the question.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju - I've added a link to [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](http://askubuntu.com/q/65083)

Comment: Thank you. I have MATE on a mini laptop and like it a lot. I'll check on your suggested options list.