# Choosing which download to have

Tags: 16.04

Is it possible to download ubuntu 16.04 for an i3 based machine which doesn't connect to the internet by first downloading to an amd based machine and then creating a bootable usb? (The download page detects the amd and starts to download the version for that, so I need to be able to choose one suitable for an i3 processor and get that one, I already have ubuntu on the amd machine).

Comment: There are no versions "for amd" or "for intel". It is unclear what are you asking. "amd64" works on both Intel and AMD 64-bit CPUs.

Comment: To be fair, the versions are called "amd" and "i386", but the difference is really whether your machine is 32-bits (i386) or 64-bits (amd). Your i3 based machine is 64-bits, so the amd version is the one you need. [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) is a page with all download links.

Comment: Ah - all is clear now - thank you so much for this answer. I will download the amd version then since the target machine (and the one I am downloading onto) are both 64 bit machines. Thanks for the prompt reply and clear explanation.

Comment: Hi @Jos, you're free to post your comment as an answer. Then it can be [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by Steve and you can earn some reputation. :)

Answer (score 5):

AMD64 is just another name for the [x86_64 CPU architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64). Points relevant to you:

- Your CPU supports it. There a no 32bit-only Intel i3s.
- It's faster than i386, [often demonstrably](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose).
- Less relevant these days is that 64bit applications do use *slightly* more RAM. But you can have more directly addressable RAM. And RAM is cheap.

On balance, 64bit is the clear winner these days.
Get that, ignore that it says AMD in the arch name. It's just a name.