# How to install gitlab in Ubuntu 14.04 x86

Tags: 14.04, gitlab

I have tried to install gitlab community edition following the instructions given on the [website](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404). First of all I used Ubuntu server 14.04 of 32 bit because I had 2 GB of RAM.

When I followed the instruction given below:

```
sudo apt-get install curl openssh-server ca-certificates postfix
curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

I got the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package gitlab-ce
```

I checked that there isn't any package   gitlab-ce in my repository:

```
$ apt-cache search gitlab
ruby-grack - Git Smart HTTP Server Rack implementation in Ruby/Rack
ruby-grit - Ruby Git bindings
ruby-omniauth-ldap - LDAP strategy for Ruby OmniAuth library
```

I have searched in the [package cloud](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce) and I couldn't find a package of gitlab x86 for Ubuntu 14.04 trusty.

I considered [alternative installation methods.](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/) but in this case I didn't see a way to do this.

I have considered downloading source code and compile it for 32-bit.
Is it the best way or are there other ways?

**Edit**

Output of apt-get update:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:3 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [72 B]
Get:4 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release [9359 B]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [528 kB]
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:3 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [72 B]
Get:4 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Get:5 http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release [9359 B]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [528 kB]
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Get:7 http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en [4593 B]
Get:8 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Get:9 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [16.2 kB]
Hit https://packages.gitlab.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit https://packages.gitlab.com trusty/main Sources
Get:10 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.5 kB]
Get:11 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [457 kB]
Hit https://packages.gitlab.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Get:12 https://packages.gitlab.com trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-es
Ign https://packages.gitlab.com trusty/main Translation-en
Ign https://packages.gitlab.com trusty/main Translation-es
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [13.1 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [4301 B]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en [2201 B]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en [3349 B]
Get:17 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en [7340 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [86.6 kB]
Get:19 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en [3842 B]
Get:20 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [207 kB]
Get:21 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages [13.3 kB]
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Get:22 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages [43.2 kB]
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:23 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en [7493 B]
Get:24 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en [1215 B]
Get:25 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en [28 B]
Get:26 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en [36.8 kB]
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-es
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-es
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-es
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-es
Fetched 1593 kB in 39s (40.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
```

Comment: I don't think there are any breaking differences between 14.04 and 16.04, so you should be able to use the instructions in this DigitalOcean tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: @blendenzo If you read my question and see the first procedure is the same, that's work for 64 bit OS no for 32 bit. What I try to do is install gitlab in Ubuntu Server 32 bit

Comment: Oh, 32-bit. https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1404 says: "GitLab packages are built for 64bit systems. For 32bit OS, consider alternative installation methods." Anyway, you can install 64-bit Ubuntu on systems with 2 GB of RAM. Just install 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: @muruI edited my question and I included the output of sudo apt-get update like you suggest me

Comment: @muru I have tried to find an  alternative installation methods in the suggested link , but I couldn't found a way and my team don't like the idea of install 64-bit Ubuntu on systems with 2 GB of RAM, Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Cyberguille why not? Anyway, try installing from source: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md Also: from personal experience, Gitlab is a bit RAM heavy. 4 GB is a minimum, IMO.

Comment: I know but I haven't other options right now and in other hand check this [what are the differences between 32 bit and 64 bit and which should I choose](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)

Comment: @Cyberguille What are your team's reasons for not wanting to install 64-bit? Even on lower spec machines, 64-bit OS will give you better performance every time.  Check these Phoronix benchmark results of 32-bit Ubuntu vs 64-bit Ubuntu on a machine with 1 GB of RAM: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_x86_1304&num=4

Comment: @Cyberguille Sorry, I missed your post right above mine. I read that link, and I understand why your team would interpret it that way, but it's not the full picture. How much RAM and swap is being consumed does not equate to performance.  The Phoronix link I provided is looking at actual performance tests. Like many of the commenters on the thread you linked said: the performance gain is worth the extra RAM usage.