# Can I install 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on a Pentium(R) B960 PC?

Tags: system-installation, hardware

Can I successfully install ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64 on a PC with a Pentium CPU B960 @ 2.20 GHz and 2GB of RAM?

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop should answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: 2GB of RAM is the problem. Consider to increase it, or use lightweight distro as Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: Yes, you can. Lubuntu or Xubuntu would be advisable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install a 64-bit version of an operating system, for as per [CNET](https://www.cnet.com/products/intel-pentium-b960-2-2-ghz-processor-mobile/specs/) your Pentium is a 64-bit processor. However, it is [not a very fast processor](https://browser.geekbench.com/processors/905), and when combined with the small amount of RAM you have, it will be a relatively slow machine. Choosing [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/downloads/), [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/download), [Ubuntu-MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/), or [another lightweight distro](https://fossbytes.com/best-lightweight-linux-distros/) will probably result in a more pleasing user experience. The first three are preferred because this is a *buntu-centric support site, and we can't help with non-*buntu issues.

You may also wish to consider use of a 32-bit distro, instead of a 64-bit, as [64-bit apps use about 50% more RAM than their 32-bit counterparts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose).

Using a distro which has the Linux kernel 4.15 or higher [protects you against Spectre/Meltdown hacks](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/1/28/173). The lesser-used distros may not be using kernel 4.15; Ubuntu [18.04 family distros do](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Linux_kernel_4.15).