# Can 32 bit use HDMI?

Tags: 64-bit, hdmi, 32-bit

I want to buy a desktop, and use Ubuntu with it. My question is: Can I have a 32 bit computer with HDMI? Also, will it be beneficial to purchase a 64 bit computer, when it comes to Ubuntu?

Comment: Your second question is a duplicate: [Why not use 64-bit Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1441/why-not-use-64-bit-ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu supports HDMI output, but when buying the desktop just watch out that the Display output has at least one DVI or one HDMI output.

I say it doesn't really matter if you use 64 or 32 but if you want 4GB or more RAM you need to use 64bit