# Why 32bit installation of Ubuntu is recommended?

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not use 64-bit Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441/why-not-use-64-bit-ubuntu)

[image]

When I tried to download Ubuntu, I have two options : 32bit and 64bit, and 32bit is recommended. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Some CPUs like the Intel Atom are 32 bit, and lots of older hardware don't have 64 bit drivers.

Comment: also look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/1441/why-not-use-64-bit-ubuntu

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Why not use 64-bit Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1441/why-not-use-64-bit-ubuntu) and /or [Difference between 32bit and 64 bit?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/difference-between-32bit-and-64-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 32-bit version of Ubuntu will run on most modern computers, but 64-bit has more specific requirements.  There are a few things that won't run well with the 64-bit version (although these don't seem to be many), so the 32-bit version is recommended just to cover all the bases, I think.  However, if you have a 64-bit computer, odds are that everything you need will run on it and will do so very well.

For example, I was able to get the Linksys AE1000 wireless access point to work just fine with my 32-bit Ubuntu, but when I changed to the 64-bit version I could no longer get the AE1000 to work.  (Perhaps there's a fix but I was never able to find it.)  However, that wasn't a big deal for me, and overall the 64-bit version feels a bit faster and it really runs everything else I've tried.

And although the 64-bit version is called AMD, it works as well on Intel 64-bit processors.

Comment: Heck, I've tried the 64-bit version. It does have an edge in performance, but not that much. I'd stick with the 32-bit version for now.