# Which 11.04 file do I download?

Tags: 11.04

Should be an easy enough question for you Ubuntu gurus out there. I need to know which Ubuntu file to download for a 64 bit disk image on [this](http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/) webpage. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: See http://www.ubuntu.com/download if you want to get the latest version (which is **not** 11.04!). Although 32-bit is marked recommended there, if you have a modern machine, you [likely want the 64-bit iso](http://askubuntu.com/q/1441/6969)

Comment: The latest version has some funky UI. Additionally, Lekensteyn, I specifically said I wanted 64 bit 11.04. I just wasn't sure which.

Answer (score 8):

Actually the one that says **64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop CD** is the one you want "For a Desktop/Laptop".

If you want it for a server installation then go with the one that says **64-bit PC (AMD64) server install CD**

64Bit Desktop - http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso

64Bit Server - http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.iso

64Bit Desktop (Torrent) - http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

64Bit Server (Torrent) - http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-server-amd64.iso.torrent

Comment: Thanks for the torrent links too, Luis. Great help everyone.

Comment: No problem. If it solves your doubt please feel free to accept the answer. Enjoy askubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want this one:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the default UI for both 11.04 and 11.10 is unity. 11.04 was unity's debut release. Personally, while it was a little strange at first, I have come to love it. Very intuitive and attractive. With 11.10, they introduced a number of improvements such that I am really bummed that one of my laptops is stuck in 11.04 due to its video card support in 11.10 is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso      64bit live cd [for fresh install]
ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso       32bit live cd [for fresh install]

ubuntu-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso    64bit alternate cd [for upgrading from existing ubuntu]
ubuntu-11.04-alternate-i386.iso     32bit alternate cd [for upgrading from existing ubuntu]

Answer (score -1):

you have to download  this [ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso)