# Should I run Ubuntu 64bit on a laptop with 2GB of RAM?

Tags: 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Ubuntu Download recommend 32-bit install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1441/why-does-ubuntu-download-recommend-32-bit-install)

I'm using an Asus K43E laptop with:
- Intel Core i3 Sandy Bridge 2.1GHz
- 2GB DDR3
- Onboard graphics

On the Ubuntu download page, the 32bit version is marked as "recommended", but the community documentation page suggests otherwise:

> Unless you have specific reasons to choose 32-bit, we recommend 64-bit to utilise the full capacity of your hardware.

I use my laptop mostly for Eclipse, apart from regular office applications, then does it make any difference when choosing between 32bit and 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its better. I am using 64 bit as well. Not much visual difference but yeah since your hardware supports try 64 bit - No harm for sure :)