# Is it OK to use 64bit ubuntu for development purposes?

Tags: 64-bit

I'm trying to install 32/64 bit ubuntu on my 6GB memory equipped PC.
I'm going to use the ubuntu PC mainly for development purposes - Xilinx FPGA development, gcc both for 8086 and ARM software development including Linux kernel compile.

Is it OK to use 64bit ubuntu for these purposes? When I tried to download ubuntu 32bit version is recommended, so I wonder if anything is wrong with 64 bit ubuntu for whatever reason.

Comment: The reason that 32-bit Ubuntu is "*recommended*" is because it is less likely to cause problems. I believe the fear is that if the 64-bit were recommended then a user with a 32-bit only PC might attempt to install it and fail. What sort of development are you asking about?

Comment: possibe duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/1441/why-does-ubuntu-download-recommend-32-bit-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With FPGA development you're building a cross-compilation toolchain regardless(the Xilinx software), so it makes no difference.  64-bit is fine.  There is a case to be made for developing for i386 on i386 and not needing to cross-compile.  In this case, it's a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the 64-bit version of Ubuntu. I've been using it for years. The 64-bit version of Ubuntu can run 32-bit as well as 64-bit programs.

The reason the 32-bit version is recommended is because older computers might have a CPU that doesn't support 64-bit. If you have a computer with a 64-bit CPU you can use the 64-bit version without any problems.